# Why are subviews in modal popovers misaligned/shifted in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, popover, subview

I have iOS apps in which the popovers worked and everything lined up according to the storyboards... in iOS 12.

Then Apple released iOS 13.3

Now all popover subviews are misaligned/shifted, vertically or horizontally depending on the position of the arrow.

**Same exact code in both cases**.   Only difference is the iOS version.

Both screenshots are from the same app with a Deployment Target of iOS 12.0

Another thing... all the .frame values are the same in both pics.  For example, the upper left button frame is ( 20, 20, 50, 50 ) in both cases.

Does anyone know how to fix this?   Has anyone else encountered this?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.   Thank you.

[image: Perfect top and bottom margins in iOS 12]

[image: iOS 13 moves all subviews up]

Comment: I came up with my own solution.  It is not elegant, but it works.  Since all the views are tagged, I do a fast enumeration through all views and update each .frame by adding 12.0 to origin.x or origin.y for a left or top arrow, respectively.  Thanks for another unnecessary headache Apple.  If anyone needs the solution as bad as I did, I will post it.